# Getting Error while running the class

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, apexrest, business-logic

You have uncommitted changes ..
I am running it from anonymous
Below is my class, i am not doing any DML ,just hitting api
I am hitting the api to get different salesforce instance Status and sending email based on status

**I am getting email for first for but then getting error->uncommitted changes**

```
public class APIHandler{
        
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void GetResponse(){
        try{
            list<string> apiKeys = new list<string>();
            apiKeys.add('SA11');
            apiKeys.add('Sp21');
            apikeys.add('NA21');
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HTTPResponse res = new httpresponse();
            Http httpreq = new Http();
            for(integer i=0;i<apikeys.size();i++){
                string endpointURL = 'https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/'+apikeys[i]+'/status/preview' ;
                req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
                req.setMethod('GET');
                req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');         

                res= httpreq.send(req);  
                Map<String, Object> metadata_Map = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                if(metadata_Map.get('status')!='OK') {
                    system.debug('Inside If---:');
                    sendEmail(string.valueof(metadata_Map.get('status')),string.valueof(metadata_Map.get('key')));
                }        
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            string ErrMsg = e.getMessage();
            System.debug ('Exc occurred: ' + ErrMsg);
        }
    }
    public static void sendEmail(string status,string key) {
        //code to send an email 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email still counts as a DML for purposes of the callout limit. Also, you shouldn't send one email at a time, as there is a hard limit of 10 Messaging.sendEmail calls per transaction.

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void GetResponse(){
    Messaging.SingleEmail[] emails = new Messaging.SingleEmail[0];
    ...
    for(Integer i = 0; i < apikeys.size(); i++) {
        ...
        // Do Callout //
        ...
        mails.add(createEmail(status, key));
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

Comment: Thanks SFDCFOX, I need to hit this API in every 10 mIn using batch

Comment: let me add updated code